# Bonnet latch bolts for VW Polo MK4

Tags: vw, part-identification

I bought a cat-C VW Polo MK4 that has obviously had some front end damage. The catch that holds the bonnet down is very loose. I'm talking about the part that's actually attached to the bonnet, not the static part that it latches on to.

This catch should be held on with three bolts, mine is held on with two very ill-fitting (non-matching) bolts. I'm pretty sure the bonnet itself is new, but this catch is probably the original and doesn't have its original bolts. The whole unit nearly fell off the bonnet today, I need to bolt it on properly. I'm happy with the level of work required, it's only 3 bolts.

What bolts do I need to buy? I don't mine original VW parts or a third-party replacement part, in fact I'm expecting it to be a standard size bolt. I'm having trouble researching this because most things I read on the internet relate to the lower part of the latch unit and hoping someone here might know what I need!

Comment: Are you talking about the loop part which attaches to the bonnet (hood) or are you talking about the mechanism which holds this loop when you shut the hood?

Comment: I'm talking about the actual loop part attached to the bonnet, the part with the "hook" on it. I'm not talking about the lower mechanism that holds the hook when the bonnet is shut. NOT this part: http://s979.photobucket.com/user/Paneuropean/media/HoodLatch1.jpg.html (I know that's the wrong car)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I cannot find any reference to them anywhere, my best suggestion to you is to go to the VW parts counter and ask them. They should have a computer which will show pictures of your vehicle with the parts exploded to reveal detail. You should be able to zoom in on the area you are looking at (the hood latch loop area) and find the bolt. Since buying parts this way is very expensive, you can do one of four things as I see it:

- Buy the part at the dealership if money is not an issue. I would expect to pay about 3-4x what you could find it for on the economy.
- Buy one of the bolts, then go down to your local hardware store and match this bolt to find the other two.
- Get the part number from the VW parts counter and find it online. This would be a much cheaper option than #1 if you are looking for genuine VAG parts.
- If available, go to a junk yard (wrecking/parts/bone yard ... whatever you like to call it ...) and find a car just like yours (or something near to it) and pull the bolts. You can usually get out of a junk yard very cheaply if you are just looking for nuts/bolts.

Hope this gives you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! I'm going to have a poke about in my local scrapyard, I'm sure I'll be able to find what I'm looking for, and they should be dead easy to pull.